# Há outro meio de abreviar "por cento"?

Tags: abreviações

Estou precisando escrever de forma reduzida a medida **por cento**. Infelizmente eu não posso utilizar o símbolo **%** por motivos técnicos. Há alguma outra maneira de abreviar essa medida?

Procuro exemplos que sejam semelhantes a essas outras medidas:

> **ct** - quilate, **pt** - ponto, **cm** - centímetro, **mm** - milímetro

Talvez algo como **pc**? Ou estou indo pelo caminho errado?

Comment: por cento não é uma medida....quer dizer um número x por 100 de algo: 10 por cada 100; vinte por cada 100.

Comment: @Lambie, há controvérsias. Pesquisando, denominam porcentagem como medida, razão, equação, índice e alguns outros nomes. Talvez todos estejam certos, talvez alguns. Há alguma pergunta sobre por aqui? Podemos abrir uma...

Comment: por cento quer dizer X unidades por cada 100 delas. Pessoalmente, não acho que medida seja uma definição exata.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A porcentagem divide uma quantidade em 100 percentis (percentil), que pode ser mais dividida com decimais (0,5 percentil; 0,01 percentil).

Embora seja mais comumente utilizado para expressar diferença entre porcentagens, existe também *pp*.

> De 2010 a 2015, houve uma redução de 50% a 30%, redução de 20pp.

---

Com o objetivo de se expressar quantidade percentual, pode-se utilizar:

> 1%. 25%.
>
> 1pp. 25pp.
>
> 1 percentil. 25 percentis.
>
> 1 parte de 100. 25 partes de 100.

Alternativamente:

> 1/100. 25/100 [1/4].
>
> 0,01. 0,25.

Comment: Atenção: «pp» é diferente de «%»! Uma redução de 50% para 30% é uma redução de 40%, mas é uma redução de 20pp.

Comment: Muito interessante a resposta, porém uma breve pesquisa me mostrou que **pp** é abreviatura de **ponto percentual** (é isso?) e entendi a diferença que o @ANeves descreveu. Posso estar querendo demais, mas é possível incrementar o pp em uma frase como: _O salário mínimo tem o aumento de **13pp** a partir do ano que vem_? Desculpem-me ser detalhista demais, mas estou curioso.

Comment: @bio é isso, sim. E não, nessa frase não funciona. Só uma percentagem pode aumentar em pontos percentuais; um valor que não seja uma percentagem não aumenta em pontos percentuais, porque não é composto por pontos percentuais; aumenta em percentagem. pp significa +- "aumento do valor percentual", por oposição ao porcento que significa +- "aumento proporcional do valor". 15pp significa que uma dada percentagem aumentou em mais 15 pontos percentuais (100% -> 115%, 20% -> 35%, 540% -> 555%). 15% significa que um valor aumentou para 1.15 vezes ele (600€ -> 690€, 20 horas -> 23 horas; 5L -> 5,75L).

Comment: Hmm... por exemplo, a inflação homóloga pode ter um aumento em pp: a inflação do ano passado pode ter sido 2.5%, e a deste ano 3.1%, o que é um aumento de 0.6pp (2.5+0.6=3.1).

Comment: @ANeves, entendi a diferença! Não queria entrar muito nesse universo matemático, mas ficou muito mais claro agora. Entretanto, parece que essa resposta não resolve a minha dúvida, embora talvez esteja correta. Precisaria que fossem equivalentes **pp** e **por cento**. Será que há outra alternativa?

Comment: Talvez seja a hora do emprego de um neologismo? :)

Comment: @bio Neologismos não cabem muito bem a abreviações. Porém você poderia fazer: "*Texto texto texto* são 30 porcento (pc), [...] *texto texto texto* totalizando 20pc do valor inicial.".

Comment: @William, legal, sou um pouco ignorante, obrigado pelo toque. A princípio informar que **pc** no caso é porcento e colocá-lo entre parênteses. Dali em diante utilizá-lo, certo? Isso em todo o texto ou no começo de cada frase? Não tem uma definição, né?

Comment: @bio Sempre que conveniente, no início de cada capítulo, por exemplo. Nenhuma vez até se houver um glossário.

Comment: porcentagem e por cento não é a mesma coisa.